# How to change indicator manually in flutter introduction screen

Tags: flutter

I want to know how to move between pages in [flutter introduction screen](https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen). To clarify the problem, I want to go back a page when skip button is pressed.

So far I have done this:

```dart
class _IntroPageState extends State<IntroPage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  void _onIntroEnd(context) {
    getIt<IntroLocalDataSource>().setIntroSeenState(true);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(SignInPage.id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final strings = Languages.of(context);
    final bodyStyle = Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .subtitle2
        ?.copyWith(fontSize: k16TextFontSize);
    final titleStyle = Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .headline1
        ?.copyWith(fontSize: k20TextFontSize);

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            child: IntroductionScreen(
              onChange: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              rtl: true,
              globalBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              showNextButton: false,
              rawPages: strings.introScreenTitles.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                int idx = entry.key;
                String val = entry.value;

                return Center(
                    child: IntroCardWidget(
                  index: idx,
                  title: val,
                  bodyStyle: bodyStyle,
                  titleStyle: titleStyle,
                  image: Assets.introImages[idx],
                  description: strings.introScreenDescriptions[idx],
                ));
              }).toList(),
              showDoneButton: false,
              curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
              showSkipButton: currentIndex != 0,
              skip: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    elevation: 0,
                    primary: kLightTextColor,
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      currentIndex--; // <<--------- This does not work
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_left_rounded,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  )),
              dotsDecorator: DotsDecorator(
                  color: kLightTextColor.withOpacity(.15),
                  activeSize: Size(20, 10),
                  activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
                  activeColor: kLightTextColor),
              controlsPadding: kIsWeb
                  ? const EdgeInsets.all(12.0)
                  : const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: Spacings.paddingSm,
                      horizontal: Spacings.paddingXs),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: Spacings.margin5Xl, minHeight: Spacings.margin5Xl),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: Spacings.margin5Xl),
          child: currentIndex != 3
              ? Container()
              : ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: Spacings.padding5Xl,
                        vertical: Spacings.paddingSm),
                    child: Text(
                      strings.goToVerificationPageBtnText,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: k16TextFontSize, color: kDarkTextColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    elevation: 1,
                    primary: kLightTextColor,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Spacings.radiusLg),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

But the page does not change. It seems to make sense, as the index is not passed to the **IntroductionScreen** widget. So I was wondering how to navigate in these pages as will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted.
It could be done with using keys & calling **IntroductionScreenState**'s methods.

After going through the source code of library, it seems it is changing pages using this public method:

```dart
Future<void> animateScroll(int page) async {
    setState(() => _isScrolling = true);
    await _pageController.animateToPage(
      max(min(page, getPagesLength() - 1), 0),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animationDuration),
      curve: widget.curve,
    );
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() => _isScrolling = false);
    }
}
```

and also has these methods for going forward & backward:

```dart
void next() => animateScroll(_currentPage.round() + 1);

void previous() => animateScroll(_currentPage.round() - 1);
```

From this point, it was just a matter of calling the methods of this state when needed. This could be done using keys:

```dart
GlobalKey<IntroductionScreenState> _introScreenKey =
      GlobalKey<IntroductionScreenState>();
```

```dart
IntroductionScreen(
  key: _introScreenKey,
  skip: ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      elevation: 0,
      primary: kLightTextColor,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
    _introScreenKey.currentState?.previous(); // <<----- This here
    },
    child: Icon(
      Icons.keyboard_arrow_left_rounded,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    )),
)
```

And ofcourse it is pretty easy to navigate directly to any page using the **animateScroll()**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using navigator, you should give a try to Navigator.pop()

`onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); }`

[here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) you can find some examples

Comment: Navigator pops the page, but each intro screen is a state. So it does not work either.